# Implementation of Scytale cipher (encryption and decryption)

Tags: java, beginner

This is web exercise 3.1.41. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> The [scytale cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scytale) is one of the first cryptographic devices used for
> military purposes. (See [The Code Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385495323).) It
> was used by the Spartans in the fifth century BCE. To scramble the
> text, you print out every kth character starting at the beginning,
> then every kth character starting at the second character, and so
> forth. Write a program implements this encryption scheme.

Here is my program:

```
public class ScytaleCipher 
{
    public static String encrypt(String text, int kth)
    {
        int textLength = text.length();
        String encrypted = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < kth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i+j < textLength; j += kth)
            {
                encrypted += String.valueOf(text.charAt(i+j));
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String text, int kth)
    {
        return encrypt(text, kth-1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int kth = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String message = "";
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            String word = StdIn.readString();
            message += word;
        }
        // to encrypt
        System.out.println(encrypt(message, kth));
        // to decrypt
        //System.out.println(decrypt(message, kth));
    }
}
```

[StdIn](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book. I checked my program and it works.

Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some suggestions for your code.

### Use `java.lang.StringBuilder` to concatenate String in a loop.

It's generally more efficient to use the builder in a loop, since the compiler is unable to optimize it by itself while translating your code into bytecode; The compiler will not use the `java.lang.StringBuilder` in complex loops and your method will take more time and more memory to execute, since the String Object is immutable (a new instance will be created each iteration).

```java
StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < kth; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; i + j < textLength; j += kth) {
      encrypted.append(text.charAt(i + j));
   }
}
return encrypted.toString();
```

### When concatenating a primitive into a string, you don’t need to convert it.

You can add the primitive (int, double, float, char, ect) directly into the string by using the [assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) (+, +=).

**Before**

```java
encrypted += String.valueOf(text.charAt(i+j));
```

**After**

```java
encrypted += text.charAt(i+j);
```